# Async/Await performance within Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, performance, silverlight-5.0, async-await

I recently have performed some testing with regards to the async/await(asyncctp) functionality in Silverlight 5.

The following hardware was used for both tests:

- Intel snb 2.3g
- 8g DDR
- Windows 7 - 64 bit
- Silverlight 5
- SQL Server 2008 - R2

The test logic is as follows:

1. **Without async/await:**

   ```
   public void LoadMasterItem(string strUNIT_ID)
   {
       **DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;**
       ctx.OBS_UNITs.Clear();
       this.IsMasterItemBusy = true;
       ctx.Load(ctx.GetOBS_UNITQuery().Where(p => p.UNIT_ID == strUNIT_ID)).Completed += (sender, e) =>
       {
           this.MasterItem = ctx.OBS_UNITs.FirstOrDefault();
           this.IsMasterItemBusy = false;
            LoadDataArgs args = ExceptionManager.CheckDataContextResult(sender, args);
            **var ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).Ticks;**
           **string str = ts.ToString();**
       };
   }
   ```
2. **With async/await:**

   ```
   public **async** Task<LoadDataArgs> LoadMasterItem(string UNIT_ID)
   {
       **DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;**
       ctx.OBS_UNITs.Clear();
       var oper = await ctx.Load(ctx.GetOBS_UNITQuery().Where(p => p.UNIT_ID == UNIT_ID)).AsTask();
       LoadDataArgs args = ExceptionManager.CheckDataContextResult(oper);
       if (args.LoadState)
       {
           this.MasterItem = oper.Entities.FirstOrDefault();
       }

       **var ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dt).Ticks;**
       **string str = ts.ToString();**
       return args;
   }
   ```

Ticks for experiment 1 : 5304010
Ticks for experiment 2 : 30001

I was curious as to why and how the use of async/await would improve my Silverlight application to such a significant degree. If my tests were 'unfair' please also give me some comments on how they could be improved.

---

I have made the "str" value bind to the UI not using debugging mode. These were hosted in IIS and executed in IE9.

The resuls are as follows:

Ticks for 1 : 5504010
Ticks for 2 : 5680325

Thank you for the responses, it seems I made a mistake regarding the actual performance.

Comment: Are you sure your other changes had no effect?

Comment: Both samples called the same ria service which was used for querying the same table. I also ran the tests separately and closed other applications. And I have tried on my college's computer and get almost the same result.

Comment: And did they both get the same actual results? Note that you're not actually *doing* anything with `str` - so how did you observe the effect? If you were running this in a debugger, that could easily have a huge effect. Run *outside* the debugger, logging the effects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the load operation actually completed when you check the time in your second sample. The method returned the task which executes asynchronously, doesn't necessarily mean the load has performed by the time you return from the async method.

Comment: But I trully get the load operation result by calling the 2nd method in UI when the code step into "string str = ts.ToString();"

Comment: And I personally feel(maybe kind of subjective) the await sample  loads data a little faster than the without counterpart after running them separately in IE9.

Answer (score 1):

The await operator is just to help your code to be more readable and less complex when dealing with chaining calls.